# Como recibir un json en C#

Tags: mysql, c#, asp.net

la api que creé me da este resultado:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre":"cali"
    }
]
```

y necesito poner el nombre en un combobox por metogo get

mi intento de codigo da error: Error en el servidor remoto: (415) Unsupported Media Type en la linea del form *string respuesta = await GetHttp();*

```
 internal class usuario
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string tel { get; set; }

        public string dir { get; set; }

        public string dir_dat { get; set; }
        public int idciudad { get; set; }

        public List<usuario> usuarios { get; set; } 
    }
```

**LLAMADO API**

```
 public async void llenarcombo()
        {


            string respuesta = await GetHttp();
            MessageBox.Show(respuesta);


           
        }

        private async Task<string> GetHttp() {
            string url = "http://localhost:49146/api/usuario";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        
        
        
        }
```

**API**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(usuario usu)
        {

            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource);

            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();



            myCommand.Connection = connection;
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "llenar_ciudad";

            MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

            connection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);



            
            return new JsonResult(dt);
           
            
        }
```

Lo que está en cuestion es rescatar los datos para meterlos en un ComboBox el cual el usuario escogerá una opcion para registrarse y posterior mente enviarlo a la bd por otra api la cual funciona bien, la appi utiliza una rutina de mysql que cree

intento poner mas detalles para que stack me permita subir toda esa cantidad de codigo que subi y no que que mas escribir, ignoren por completo todo esto es es sol para subiri lo que realmente importa muchas gracias por ayudar.

Comment: vuelvo a repetir.. en ningun lugar, estas llamando a la api.. deberias buscar informacion sobre eso...

Comment: actualizado, no estaba mostrando donde llamaba la api, sinembargo el error cambio

Comment: Bueno.. te recomiendo un par de cosas.. no es necesario que devuelvas explicitamente un jsonresult.. tu api va a devolver un json por defecto. Despues, no tenes que devolver un datatable completo... debes devolver solo los datos.. te recomendaria usar un ORM (entity framework, Dapper), porque lo que estas haciendo es una forma muy vieja y casi obsoleta de hacer un query...

Comment: ahora.. el error se da en el front? tu back hace todo bien?

Comment: ok... el error se da al frente y si el back todo en orden, en el postman se muestra correcto

Comment: Actualiza el codigo de esta pregunta, al error que tenes ahora...